# Advantages of algorithm W over algorithm J for type inference in Hindley-Milner type system

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, type-inference

According to [*A modern eye on ML type inference*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9c26/4be55d6e4cb1b1981bbeb0310e241c935031.pdf)

> Furthermore, for some
>   unknown reason,
>   W
>   appears to have become more popular than
>   J, even though the latter is viewed—with reason!—by Milner as a simplification of the former.  Jones’ presentation of type inference for
>   Haskell [21] does rest upon an implementation of
>   J.

Indeed, I've seen many expositions of W. But this is the first one of J that I've seen.

So does W have advantages which these notes overlook? Or is it just about avoiding mutability in Milner's presentation of J?

Comment: The link seems wrong. 
 Here's the right one: http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/publis/fpottier-appsem-2005.ps.gz

Comment: The link in the question works for me, and the correction given in the above comment was flagged as a security risk by my antivirus software.

Comment: @hatch22 Perhaps the issue that the link in the comment is a download from an http page. My browser does not seem to like downloading a file via a "http"-link (the comment) on a "https" page (this page). But the link in the comment links to the same website as semantic scholar (although with a different extension), and the link that semantic scholar lists is also available on the [researchers' website](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/biblio/pottier.html). In any case, I don't see anything nefarious.

Comment: Glad to know.  Was the link in the question corrected without being noted?  I had no problem with it.

Comment: @hatch22 Yes, it was.